# NoSQL Database Design

Tags: mysql, sql, database, web, nosql

I'm looking at SQL & NoSQL Databases - namely MySQL and DynamoDB (both at AWS).

I'm building a dating/social network and demos I've built have been using a MySQL Database with around 50 tables for logical separation of data and then using SQL queries (often with joins) to extract required chucks of data to send back to browsers.

I'm moving to AWS and are doing a rebuilt of the system and wanted to know if it would be possible to write a site like this 100% in NoSQL. I understand you don't know the specifics of the site but it could be compared to any other dating/social network like facebook (obviously more involved) or Eharmony/Match Maker etc...

Could a Social Site be built 100% on NoSQL? or would a mix of NoSQL & SQL be move realistic?

thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a very difficult question to answer without a deeper understanding of exactly what features you're after, and what language you are going to be writing the site in.  There are lots of different types of NoSQL solutions.

NoSQL databases like Dynamo and Cassandra are *Key-Value Stores*.  They offer a very different set of features than *Document Databases* like MongoDB and RavenDB.  There are many other types as well.

Personally, I would be more than comfortable writing a social media site based entirely on RavenDB.  But that's because I tend to focus on Domain Driven Design, and like to write in .Net/C#.  It has all the features you would need, like querying indexes, map/reduce for big data jobs, full-text search, and spatial distance proximity searches.  You could use their http/rest api if you wanted to program from php or javascript, but their C# client is much easier to use.

Your requirements may be different than mine would be though.  I would encourage you to try out several different NoSQL technologies before you settle on one.  You may still find that you need a SQL (or MySQL) database for certain things that your NoSQL solution doesn't handle.  For example, RavenDB isn't recommended for ad-hoc reporting - so many people set up a separate SQL Server database and replicate data from Raven into SQL so they can provide a separate reporting database to their power users.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest thing to remember is that most noSQL engines (like [Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/)) don't support querying, so that has to be a factor in your design (i.e. many things you take for granted in SQL like JOINs are much harder in a noSQL solution). With that being said, you most definitely can build full-featured applications using a noSQL solution. I encourage you to look into resources available from the many providers out there, like Cassandra, MongoDB, Dyanamo, and many others.

Comment: They support querying, but the queries you can run are often a *lot* more limited.

Comment: Good point. A better way I could have stated that was "don't support as wide a range of querying".

Comment: MongoDB supports a non-SQL way of querying things and has indexes, other key-value stores support range selectors. "NoSQL" just means, in essence, "No SQL queries" but not no queries. The distinction is important because some NoSQL systems are actually considerably better than SQL in certain problem domains.

Comment: I agree with tadman, e.g., level 2 drivers like Playorm supports large range of SQLs (including JOINS). Though in JPA way.